# flutter build method executes before async function completes

Tags: flutter, dart

i would like to move to another screen when async if statement satisfies it does calls the if statement but the build method already executes is there any way i can call the build method when async function completes ?

```
  void initState() {
  nickCheck();
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }
  nickCheck() async{
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final nick = prefs.getString('nick');
    if(nick.isNotEmpty){
      Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => intro(nick),
    ),
    );}
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
    return Scaffold(
```

Comment: my bad my search keywords weren't accurate

Answer (score 0):

You should do workaround like below.

````
var nick;  // Move variable here
void initState() {
  nickCheck();
    super.initState();
  }
  nickCheck() async{
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    nick = prefs.getString('nick');
    if(nick.isNotEmpty){
      Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => intro(nick),
    ),
    );}
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (nick == null)
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
    else {
        SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
        return Scaffold(```

    }
````